# WordPress CMS Inquiry

Tags: custom-post-types, cms

I'm pretty familiar with WordPress and have used it on various projects both as a blog as well as a fully-functional CMS using custom post types, etc.

I am about to embark on a project for a client that includes a site that displays a few clothing pieces. Each piece will also display its different color options (ex: The "XXX" shirt will come in Black, Red and White and should be able to view colors when you click on a color swatch).

There will be 30 products, give or take a few, but this number is pretty set in stone.. There won't be the situation in which 20 more products will need to be added.

So my first inclination was just to make a custom post type called "clothing" and create each clothing piece. From there, I would create each piece's color option as a child page of the parent clothing piece page.

I know there are various ways to approach a project like this but I wanted to get some input and maybe some recommendations on how to go about with something like this.

Comment: Can you explain your thought process on why/how a color option deserves to be its own page? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a Custom Post Type, "Product", and then have custom taxonomies:

1. Size
2. Color

This method will facilitate viewing (and querying) by any combination of Product, Size, and Color.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is a really good solution to a number of structures. If I understand your requirements correctly, Wordpress would properly work. I've used WP on a large and diverse number of websites, if you are able to design the right architecture in terms of meta values for each of the custom post types then you should be alright.

I'm not entirely sure why you would make a separate page for each of the colour options, as this sounds like overkill. Maybe just have a meta field where you list the different colours and use some logic to list these colours on each of the product pages.

If you could provide a little more information about the way in which users will use the site, it might be easier to understand what it is you need.

Comment: @Tom,

I'm basically trying to find different ways to organize something similar to this: http://ashburyeyewear.com/collections/shades/ . I'll have a small amount of products and each product will have different colorways. Each colorway will be displayed as a thumbnail and when clicked, that specific colorway's full-sized image will display. 

I've also considered just having each product be it's own individual page and just having the different colorways and images be the gallery within that page. However, that organization may not be the best.